# how to install odoo community v14 & v15 in the same windows machine?

Tags: postgresql, odoo

i've some experience with odoo v14, i installed it on my windows laptop, & working fine

the problem is : when i tried to test v15, it cannot be started at all (internal server error on the browser), however, the v14 still works fine

i have tried :

- change the port of v14 to 8070, and port 8069 to v15, the v14 still works
- on odoo.conf, change the pg_path, admin_passwd, db_port, db_host

note :

- when i installed v15, the postgreSQL installation cannot be ticked, it may caused by the postgreSQL had already installed in v14
- on the folders, there is postgre folder on v14, but there isn't on v15

did i install with the correct way? what's wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the log file of Odoo 15 to see what error it shows?

Comment: hello, thank you for answering, could you guide us where is the log?

Comment: ah, my bad, i've got the log, the log file is 1 MB, there are several errors in it

Comment: i added the log file on dropbox, here is the link : https://www.dropbox.com/s/xk988r2ki5eqrd6/odoo.log?dl=0

Comment: Can you check by creating a new postgres user for odoo 15 and use that in the config file of Odoo 15?